# Want to know how many photos are uploaded by a user. Statistics table. SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my database

```
members (member_id, firstname, lastname)
members_photos (member_id, photo_id)
```

Basically I want to be able to query data in such a way to display the following

```
User     Number of photos uploaded
George   15
Steven   3
Mark     0
```

Any help?

Comment: you forgot to mention the database you're using ;)

Comment: @user1044039 What's the server name?

Comment: @user1044039 mysql, postgresql, mssql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
select firstname, count(*) 
from members 
join member_photos using(member_id) 
group by firstname
```

Comment: Consider grouping by member_id instead, though. I assume listing 'George' multiple times for different Georges is preferable to lumping them all into one...

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables and then count the number of rows.

```
SELECT 
    [firstname] as [User], 
    count(*) as [Number of photos uploaded]
FROM
    [members] m
    INNER JOIN [members_photos] mp
    ON m.[member_id] = mp.[member_id]
```